# Is there a way to switch between Android Network Security XML files?

Tags: android, android-studio

Android allows developers to set a Network Security configuration file in an XML to protect your application’s network security. I would like to switch between multiple Network Security Configuration XML files but I can’t find any documentation that discusses a way to change the Network Security XML with Java or Kotlin at runtime.

Is this even possible?

Comment: AFAIK, that is not an option. At compile time, you could use different build variants (e.g., `debug` vs. `release`).

Comment: I was looking to do it programmatically. I have been unable to find a work around.